# SOQL Filter By First Letter

Tags: soql, filters

I have recently inherited a Visualforce page that lists all Accounts in a dropdown. As the company has grown, so has the list of accounts.

Now that the account list has more than 1,000 entries and will no longer allow the page to load due to limits I need to update the UI.

The approach that the page owners would like to see is another dropdown with options "A" through "Z" which will then add a filter by the first letter of the account...

```
WHERE Name like 'A%'
```

That query is working great, but I would like to make sure that accounts that begin with a non-alpha character also work.

I would like to avoid creating a query with 26 separate not likes ...

```
 NOT (Name like 'A%' ... or Name like 'Z%')
```

What approach have others used to resolve this issue? Have I overlooked something very simple?

The solution is used only by US - English users, so we are pretty set on the 26 alpha cases, and the "other" bucket should include everything but those 26 letters.

Comment: Have you considered using a control like the jQuery autocomplete? It works great, scales well, and is easy to implement. In my experience it's a much nicer UI than a picklist with a bunch of first letters in it.

Comment: I had not considered that idea. It sounds like a great solution that I will keep in mind for the next time this issue comes to light. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Cool, definitely check it out. It's pretty easy to build a general-purpose Apex component that uses jQuery for autocomplete on any field. You can get fancy and back it with SOSL to make it really powerful - users love being able to type "Chicago" to autocomplete to any Account with Chicago in its name OR as its city value, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I would add a formula field:

```
Is_Alpha__c = IF(CONTAINS("A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H:I:J:K:L:M:N:O:P:Q:R:S:T:U:V:W:X:Y:Z", UPPER(LEFT(My_Field__c, 1))), "Yes", "No")
```

Then your "other" query has a where clause of:

```
WHERE Is_Alpha__c = 'No'
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Phil. In line with your suggestion, I added a formula field with a Starts_With_Letter__c field since the "other" bucket includes non-numeric characters as well as the numbers. I will leave this open for a while to see if there are other suggestions as well.

Comment: Updated: This way should work for everything not-alpha.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error the RegEx is not available in Formula fields (This function is available everywhere formulas exist except formula fields and custom buttons and links from http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#REGEX)

Comment: Daah thats weak.  Well then the best answer I have is pretty much what you said you didn't want to do, but in a formula field.

Comment: Thanks Phil. That is the approach that I took, although your formula is much more concise than my list of IF(LEFT(UPPER(Name), 1) = "A"...!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a "inpuText" to capture the search term, you can always use the below code:

`Public String searchAlphabet{get;set;} // bind this with inputText on VF Page`

`public List<YourObject> getObjects()`
`{`
    `String  startalphabet = searchAlphabet + '%';`

```
`List<yourObject> myObjectList = [Select all the fields that you want from yourObject where NAME LIKE: startalphabet];`

`return myObjectList;`
```

`}`

Comment: Ahh...sorry. I misread your question..I see you are using a dropdown...however the above approach should still work..instaed of binding the variable to inputText, you can bind it to the dropDown

Comment: Thanks for the input Shailesh. The problem with this approach is the "other" non-alpha values. The droplist will specify Other and should include numbers, quotes, ticks, etc.

Comment: Ohh...I missed the "other" part. Poor reading !! Sorry.